# Remote from a Win 7 workstation to a Fedora 14 sandbox

Tags: windows-7, rdp, fedora

The webmaster asked to have a Fedora 14 sandbox for him to test our website internally. The plan was that he would connect to this box via remote desktop from his Win7 machine that is part of our Server 2008 domain. I created a Fedora 14 virtual machine for him as requested and it is connected to the network. I can ping the sandbox ip from any Win7 machine but can't connect via remote desktop. The sandbox's rdp is set up to allow connections from anyone but Win7 rdp client is giving me a pretty generic "Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer..." error.

Is it possible to rdp from within a domain to a network attached linux box? Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: I have to ask, why does the Fedora machine even have a GUI?

Comment: I guess there's no particular reason other than the fact that I've never used a purely command line OS. The webmaster, who's a fairly advanced linux user, may have. Since he's the one who is going to be using it, I'll see if that's an option.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Fedora VM running on his Win7 machine with a program such as virtualbox that lets you see the desktop? if so no remote desktop connection needed.

If not then you are going to need to install some sort of remote desktop server on the Linux Machine.

For servers most people just use command line SSH (ssh server on the server and putty on the windows side)

But if you need a Gui there are many options.

For actual remote desktop use like you would do in windows the 2 most common seem to be Nomachine NX and X2GO.

NoMachine is commercial but free up to 2 connections while X2GO is totally free.

Both are easy to install and there respective websites has all the details.

You then use a client (x2go client or nx client) on the windows box to connect, also free and very easy to install.

Comment: +1 for "For servers most people just use command line SSH". WinSCP and PuTTY are all that's required.

Comment: He did mention though that his boss wants to test the website which I assume means with a browser running on linux for compatability.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the webmaster is a fairly advanced linux user so command line ssh could be an option. The remote desktop server, however, is running on Fedora 14 and is the root of my problem. If it's running, I figure we should be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

yum install xrdp
Then he can connect with win7 mstsc.exe.

Comment: there was a certain time sensitivity with this issue so we ended up just creating a winxp virtual machine instead. it's doing the trick for now but we'll probably try to change it over to Fedora in the future. I'll be sure to give this a try.

Comment: i get the feeling you have not used yum before.  You owe it to yourself to know yum or any of the Linux package managers.  The time to run "yum install xrdp" is literally the blink of an eye.     Creating a new VM host and a XP VM and install all the antivirus software, adobe flash, adobe reader, java .... takes _forever_.  Equivalent software is usually already installed in Linux.  If you want the native Adobe Reader and native Adobe Flash, then it is just a matter of adding a repository and yum install.

Comment: Thanks RJT. I am a relatively new linux user at home and this was my first attempt at integrating any linux into our work environment. Ultimately, I'm going to replace this xp vm with a Fedora box and it looks like xrdp is what we'll be using to manage it. Thanks for all your help.